# Is there way to define required class members order in the .editorconfig file?

Tags: c#, .net-5, static-code-analysis, editorconfig

I use `.editorconfig` file to define code style rules in my .Net 5 solution. Is it possible to define required class members order in the `.editorconfig`? For example, public members should appear before private, non-static members should appear before static and methods before properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define order of members in class using `editorconfig`, but you can write custom analyzer using Roslyn or use CodeMaid extensions for VS2019, not sure about VSCode extensions
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this doesn't directly answer your question since you requested the ability to configure this in `.editorconfig`, but you could consider using [StyleCop Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers), specifically [Rule SA1202](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1202.md).

Sadly, it appears that this very helpful library has gone a little stale, with no official release in almost 3 years, as of the time of writing.  I would love to see its capabilities merged into .NET Roslyn analyzers, with full `.editorconfig` support for configuring rules.